# How to fix Rails server error 'cannot load such file -- nokogiri (LoadError)' after "rails new"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, nokogiri

After every fresh `rails new` folder, when I try to run `rails server`, I  get:

```
cannot load such file -- nokogiri (LoadError)
```

I'm using Arch Linux.

- Ruby version = ruby 2.6.2
- Rails version ~> 5.2.3
- RVM 1.29.7
- Nokogiri (default: 1.10.3, 1.10.2)

If I change the version of Nokogiri from 1.10.3 to 1.10.2 in Gemfile.lock, Rails will work.
I tried removing `1.10.3` version but it's still there. I tried changing the default Nokogiri version and now I have two default versions in gem list:

```
nokogiri (default: 1.10.3, default: 1.10.2)
```

Comment: Why don't you specify a fixed version of Nokogiri on your gemfile? You shouldn't modify your Gemfile.lock, set what you want on in the Gemfile and run bundler to update the Gemfile.lock

Comment: @arieljuod , nokogiri is not added in the Gemfile. It's probably required as a dependency.

Comment: You can add it to specify a version that you want to use.